# Search in multiple columns using database query in Python/Django?

Tags: django, search

I have a model like this:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    tape_id = models.TextField()
    name = models.TextField()
    video_type = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    director = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cameraman = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    editor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time_code = models.TextField()
    tag1 = models.TextField()
```

User can search from `tape_id, name, director and cameraman` using the same search input box.
I have a search view like this:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        search_inp = request.POST['search_box']
        tape_id = Info.objects.filter(tape_id__exact=search_inp)
        res = Info.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_inp)
        res = Info.objects.filter(director__icontains=search_inp)
        res = Info.objects.filter(cameraman__icontains=search_inp)
        total_video = res.count()
        if len(res) == 0 and len(tape_id) == 0 :
            result = "No videos found!!"
            return render_to_response('no_results_only.html', {'result':result}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            date1 = [i.date for i in res]
            date = [i.strftime("%B %d, %Y") for i in date1]
            a = zip(res, date)
            return render_to_response('list_videos.html', {'a':a, 'total_video':total_video}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I thought it would work at first but it doesn't. First res variable can contain the value whereas the last res be empty which will return to the `no_results.html`. I want to deploy this search using the same input box. How can I make this work?

Comment: You know that you're rewriting `res` with each of these queries, right? Anyway, use `Q` for `OR` queries.

Comment: Yes, I realized that, I was completely unknown with Q. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to import Q to use for OR filtering:

```
from django.db.models import Q
```

Then your code should look like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    search_inp = request.POST['search_box']
    res = Info.objects.filter(
        Q(tape_id__exact=search_inp) | 
        Q(name__icontains=search_inp) |
        Q(director__icontains=search_inp) |
        Q(cameraman__icontains=search_inp)
    )
    total_video = res.count()
    if len(res) == 0:
        result = "No videos found!!"
        return render_to_response('no_results_only.html', {'result':result}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        date1 = [i.date for i in res]
        date = [i.strftime("%B %d, %Y") for i in date1]
        a = zip(res, date)
        return render_to_response('list_videos.html', {'a':a, 'total_video':total_video}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to apply `OR` conditions in the `filter`. You can refer the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for the syntax.

```
Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')
```

It will make sure that you will get an unique list of objects in the result.

Comment: In my case how can I do that? 
Q(Info.objects.filter(tape_id__exact=search_inp)) | ......... ?